# Landsat 8 - Surface reflectance panchromatic band ?

Tags: landsat-8

I ordered landsat 8 surface reflectance high level data products via Espa: http://espa.cr.usgs.gov/ordering/new.

Is it correct that there is no surface reflectance panchromatic band available after processing?

Comment: 'Panchromatic Landsat' Is this an option? http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=6b003010cbe64d5d8fd3ce00332593bf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is abolutely true!
The surface reflectance is only available for bands 1-7:

http://landsat.usgs.gov/documents/provisional_l8sr_product_guide.pdf

Comment: Do you know how I could get surface reflectance (landsat 8) for band 8?